# How to make Clojure evaluate constant local expressions at compile time

Tags: clojure

Pursuing 4Clojure [Problem 178 - Best Hand](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/178), I have this for transforming card values from characters to numbers:

```
 (fn [ch]
   (or
    ({\A 1} ch)
    ((zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10)) ch)
    (- (int ch) (int \0))))
```

*The `zipmap` expression is evaluated on every call, always producing `{\K 13, \Q 12, \J 11, \T 10}`.*

*How can we make the compiler evaluate it just once?*

---

After much brainbending, I came up with

```
(defmacro constant [exp] (eval exp))
```

... wrapping the `zipmap` call thus:

```
(constant (zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10)))
```

I think this is equivalent to

```
(eval '(zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10)))
```

... but not to `eval` without the quote:

```
(eval (zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10)))
```

Corrections, comments, and improvements welcome.

Comment: `eval` is also called at runtime, so I don't think that's improving things.

Comment: Never mind - I mistakenly thought that eval was being escaped. Still, I think my answer is a more general-purpose solution that will handle things other than compile-time literals.

Comment: You might find [Timothy Baldridge's talk on tools.analyzer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhRQmT22SSg&index=11&list=PLZdCLR02grLp__wRg5OTavVj4wefg69hM) relevant here. At around 21-22 mins in he creates a custom analyzer pass which replaces constant nodes with their return value. But as he says it's probably not worth doing for performance reasons as there's unlikely to be huge benefits, but very interesting as a learning experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `constant` macro will work for this particular situation, because the form being evaluated has only symbols that resolve to functions in `clojure.core` and compile-time literals. You might run into problems with symbol resolution in other situations, such as computing local constants from function parameters to use in an anonymous function.

A more general way to do this is to move the call to `zipmap` outside the `fn` form. One option is to store the results of the `zipmap` call in a var using `def`, as in `(def my-const (zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10)))`.

However, in this case where you're making an anonymous function, creating a globally-accessible var might be overkill. So I'd suggest putting the `fn` inside a `let` binding that captures the constant value:

```
 (let [face-cards (zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10))]
   (fn [ch]
     (or
       ({\A 1} ch)
       (face-cards ch)
       (- (int ch) (int \0)))))
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, this solution will compute the constant value at load-time, not at compile time. I have a hard time coming up with a scenario where that would matter, but it's worth pointing out that the semantics of it are slightly different than your approach.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought the `constant` macro above would be expanded at macro expansion time, and replace the `zipmap` call with the literal result. Is this wrong?

Comment: No, you-re correct - see my new comment on the post. The `constant` macro will work in some situations.

Comment: Just to be clear, I believe both the let over lambda and the def will be evaluated at load time rather than at compile time. These achieve the only-once objective in idiomatic fashion but not at compile-time.

Comment: @Alex. Thank you. More questions, I'm afraid: Why does `let` help? Is the bound expression not notionally evaluated every time the `let` form is entered? Is it then a characteristic of the compiler, not the language, that, being constant, the bound expression is evaluated just once? Why then does the compiler fail to notice that the inline expression is constant?

Comment: The `let` form is only evaluated one time; the function returned by `fn` closes over the *value* of the local bindings that were in effect when the function was created, and re-uses them each time the function is invoked.

Comment: @Thumbnail Well, yes, the expression would be evaluated every time the `let` is entered. The idea is to enter it only once. If you put this let-over-lambda construct in a `def` or placed it top-level and changed the inner `fn` to a `defn`, then it would just be evaluated once. If it were inside another function (a function generating the inner function as return value) then it would be evaluated each time the outer function is called, as desired when e.g. the map depends on parameters pasted to the generator. If you didn't want that behavior, then e.g. move the `let` outside the outer fn.

Comment: Thank you all. I understand that *let over lambda* allows me to put an evaluation as high in the lexical tree as possible. However, just as `recur` marks tail recursion, I would like a way of marking that  an expression was constant and would be so treated.

Comment: @A.Webb Finally got it - duh! Took me a while to comprehend your remarks about `def` and `defn`.

Comment: @Alex Is this a legitimate use case for the dreaded `eval`? - giving `((eval (zipmap "TJQK" (iterate inc 10))) ch)` in the question code.